# Help Me simplify: C*(A+B) + ~A*B

Tags: digital-logic, electrical

I know the answer is `AC + ~AB`, but how?

I have tried:

`B(~A+C) + AC` and stop.

Also, I have tried:

`AC + BC + ~AB` and have stopped.

There seems nowhere to go in either case.

Comment: Show what you've tried and be explicit with where you are confused. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will not give you the full solution, but the required non-trivial sidestep. You have got this far:

```
C(A + B) + A'B = AC + BC + A'B =
```

Now here is the sidestep. We know that `(A+A')` is `1`, so we can do:

```
 = AC + (A + A')BC + A'B
```

From here you will need to expand it and use the "OR absorption law" twice.

Comment: @AlanKazemian (Be sure and hit the check mark so you can close the question)

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Expanding the brackets was an obvious step but your "sidestep" was one that I had not considered. Very useful and I will bear this in mind for future tasks. A Karnaugh Map would also have provided a easy solution to the problem.